# How to run FTP server in Mininet

Tags: sdn, mininet, pox

I use `SimpleHTTPServer` Python class to set up HTTP server in `Mininet`. Now, I want to run `FTP server` but I don't know how!! Does Mininet support running FTP server? If so, how can I install that? If not, is there a workaround for that? I feel Mininet surely is able to support FTP but I couldn't find a clear solution when I google this.

Thank you very much,

Answer (score 2):

Install a FTP server on Mininet VM using "sudo apt-get install ftpd"
then connect to mininet using filezilla

Answer (score 1):

1. install lftp :  **`sudo apt-get install lftp`**
2. install inetd : **`sudo apt install openbsd-inetd`**
3. run in the destination host this command : **`inetd &`**
4. run in the source host this command : **`lftp -u user,password -e "get yourfile;quit" @ip_des`**