# use ftp to transfer a file between Mininet hosts

Tags: sdn, mininet

I want to start an ftp server on one Mininet host and access that server from another host, Here is what I've tried:

1. Installing vsftpd on the Mininet VM, the server works fine to access
   the VM itself but I cannot figure out how to run the server on a
   specific host, say a host with IP = 10.0.0.10.
2. I tried what this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41899149/how-to-run-ftp-server-in-mininet) suggested, the second answer seemed
   promising but sadly it did not work, after running the commands I
   get the following error on the destination-host:

> [connection refused]

To sum up: I would like to send a file between two Mininet hosts using ftp, I fail to start an ftp server on any specific host.

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 as my Mininet VM.

Answer (score 0):

open the shell of the exact host by:

> xterm "hostname"

then install your ftp server and start it.